# How to do filter_all in R using multiple patterns

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr, dataset

I need help with filtering a set of values across an entire data frame in R. I am using filter_all which works for a single value, but when I use a vector, it fails. The resulting data frame should not contain any values from patterns.
Please help.

```
patterns <-c(-1,-2,-3,-4)

data %>% filter_all(any_vars(. !=patterns))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `any_vars(! . %in% patterns)`. `==` and `!=` are element-wise, comparing first element to first element, second element to second element, etc. (with recycling, if the lengths don't match).  `%in%` works like a set operation. Compare `1:4 == c(1, 3)` vs `1:4 %in% c(1, 3)`:

```
1:4 == c(1, 3)
# [1] TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
1:4 %in% c(1, 3)
# [1] TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
```